# Using "extern" to declare functions with no parameters

Tags: c, xcode, macos

I am developing a plugin in C and the pointers to common functions can only be determined at runtime. As a consequence, I need to declare the functions using "extern" and all is right **except** when a function takes no parameters!

How should I properly declare and assign an external function pointer in C?

Note: I am on a Mac with Xcode 10.2.1 and my C code is embedded in a ".m" (Cocoa) file.

Comment: Start by posting how you're currently declaring it.

Comment: *all is right except when a function takes no parameters*  And what specifically is not right about that?  You have provided no code, you have not provided what's wrong. Any help you get is going to be the result of guessing.

Comment: If you define and declare a function with no parameters in your file without `extern`, how do you do this? Why do you expect it to be different with `extern`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is most likely that the function pointer `int (*f)()` is NOT a function pointer to a function taking no arguments. It is a function pointer to a function with *unspecified* arguments. Instead, use `int (*f)(void)`.

Here is an example:

```
$ cat main.c 
int foo() { return 0; }
int bar(int a) { return a; }

int main(void)
{
    int (*f)();
    f=foo;
    f=bar;
    int(*g)(void);
    g=foo;
    g=bar;
}
```

Now we compile

```
$ gcc main.c 
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:11:3: warning: assignment to ‘int (*)(void)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(int)’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  g=bar;
   ^
```

As you can see, I get no warning for the pointer `f`. Only for `g`.